# Mongodb indexing optional fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have some fields in my mongodb collection that are optional parts of a search. How can I index this query consistently (i.e. every query, regardless of parameters will use an index) if I don't know what fields the user might be querying?

Comment: Your only option would be to create a separate index on every possible field-combination.

Comment: @Philipp - I'm more confused about how you handle cases where the field might not be a part of the query. Say, for example, I was creating a service that queried grocery store nutrition data. If I've indexed the `gluenFree` field, but the user is not gluten free and doesn't add that to his/her search, how do I make sure that compound index gets used?

Comment: A compound index can also be used when only the beginning of the index is provided by the query.

Comment: Ah, so the index would only be discounted if I were to add an additional query that was not part of the index, and would not be discounted if I leave out part of the index?

Comment: When you look for more fields than the index covers, it would still be of partial use, as it can be used to limit the candidate documents which need to be scanned down to those which match the index. When you leave out fields covered by the index, these should be the last fields of the index, as any fields after a missing field are unusable.

Comment: For more information, you might want to read the documentation about [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/), especially the section about prefixes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Sparse Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the
>   indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value. The
>   index skips over any document that is missing the indexed field. The
>   index is “sparse” because it does not include all documents of a
>   collection. By contrast, non-sparse indexes contain all documents in a
>   collection, storing null values for those documents that do not
>   contain the indexed field.

```
db.addresses.createIndex( { "xmpp_id": 1 }, { sparse: true } )
```